# display an image retrieved from its URI

Tags: c#, wpf, image, type-conversion, bitmapimage

I have some problems while trying to serialize an object containing a BitmapSource field.

In fact, at the beginning, I had an ImageSource but it seems not to be serializable.
So I tried to use the associated property to store a string and to convert & convert back the image to/from the string.but no image is displayed now :-(

here is the XAML image tag:

```
<Image 
                        x:Name="bookCover"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.RowSpan="1"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        MaxWidth="200"
                        MaxHeight="320"
                        Margin="5"
                        Source="{Binding Image}" SizeChanged="bookCover_SizeChanged" >

                    </Image>
```

here is the Image property & field in the model class:

```
public string _image;

public BitmapSource Image
        {
            get => Base64ToImage(_image);
            set
            {
                _image =ImageToBase64(value);
                OnPropertyChanged("Image");
            }
        }
```

and their associated methods:

```
public static string ImageToBase64(BitmapSource bitmap)
        {

            var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
            var frame = BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap);
            encoder.Frames.Add(frame);
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                encoder.Save(stream);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
            }
        }

        public static  BitmapSource Base64ToImage(string base64)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                return BitmapFrame.Create(stream);
            }

        }
```

and here my program retrieves an image from internet via its URI and stores it:

```
var myUri=new Uri(book0.LargeImage.URL);
bookToInsert.Image = new BitmapImage(myUri);
```

thank you.

Comment: Are you really sure you want to serialize a string instead of a byte array?

Comment: You know, I will use the first working method I get...a string or a byte array are equals to me. By the way, I find it difficult to get some tutorials on how to serialize images, and on bitmap encoders...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a BitmapSource from a stream that is closed immediately after creation, you have to set `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`. Otherwise the stream would have to be kept open until the BitmapSource is actually used, e.g. displayed in an Image element.

```
public static BitmapSource Base64ToImage(string base64)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64)))
    {
        return BitmapFrame.Create(
            stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
    }
}
```

---

A couple of notes:

1. base64 encoding and decoding seems unnecessary. Better serialize a byte array.
2. Do not initially create a BitmapImage from the URL. Better directly get the image buffer by a web request.
3. You can bind the Source property of an Image element not only to an ImageSource, but also to a string, Uri or byte array. So your property may be declared as `byte[] Image`.

Try a much simpler view model like this:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private byte[] image;

    public byte[] Image
    {
        get => image;
        set
        {
            image = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Image));
        }
    }
}
```

and set the Image property like this:

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
viewModel.Image = webClient.DownloadData(book0.LargeImage.URL);
```

Or asynchronously:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
viewModel.Image = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(book0.LargeImage.URL);
```

Comment: Do not create an initial BitmapImage, as shown in the edited answer.

Comment: do you know a reference book about the .net framework, in which I could dive in to grab this kind of information ?